# Show only words in their superlative form (ends in -est) in the word list; getting all character with est

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk

```
from nltk.corpus import shakespeare

words = shakespeare.words('hamlet.xml')

words = [word.lower() for word in words]
def est(list): #Words in their superlative form (ends in -est)
    result = []
    for word in list:
        if word.endswith("est"):
            result.append(word)
    return result
            

print(est(words_list))
```

Result:

['priest', 'honest', 'mightiest', 'wisest', 'best', 'dearest', 'chiefest', 'best', 'dearest', 'chariest', 'best', 'best', 'west', 'comest', 'lightest', 'best', 'incest', 'pursuest', 'honest', 'request', 'rest', 'rest', 'rest', 'rest', 'best', 'best', 'honest', 'honest', 'honest', 'honest', 'rest', 'honest', 'lest', 'west', 'best', 'comest', 'honest', 'rest', 'honest', 'honest', 'honest', 'rest', 'best', 'tempest', 'blest', 'seest', 'littlest', 'rest', 'jest', 'jest', 'forest', 'rest', 'lowest', 'rest', 'highest', 'eldest', 'darest', 'weakest', 'strongest', 'lest', 'test', 'wisest', 'best', 'blackest', 'profoundest', 'wisest', 'knowest', 'rest', 'didest', 'unworthiest', 'quest', 'answerest', 'guest', 'guest', 'liest', 'liest', 'rest', 'jest', 'priest', 'priest', 'priest', 'rest', 'priest', 'liest', 'earnest', 'lest', 'darkest', 'best', 'arrest', 'livest', 'conquest', 'rest', 'rest', 'noblest', 'lest']

Expecting to show superlative words.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: only superlative words will show

Answer (score 0):

> `if 'est' in list[i]:`

You're filtering based on if "est" is in the word, not if it ends. Use something like

```py
list[i].endswith("est")
```

instead.